# SQL Server 2005 Linked Server using SSMS from laptop vs RDP

Tags: sql-server-2005, cisco-vpn, linked-server, named-pipes, database-connection

I connect to work network via Cisco VPN from my work laptop, which is on AD.

**Edit**

I am using SQL authentication to connect from Server A to B; in scenario #1 I can connect.
I can even connect from localhost to Server B. So, I'm wondering why I can't establish linked server connection when I use connect to Server A via SSMS and then try to setup the linked server connection.

I do have a sneaking suspicion the issue with trying to create connection via SSMS might be the VPN/firewall since I can establish the linked server connection when I RDP into server A.

**Scenario #1**

1. RDP into Server A (on same AD as my work laptop)
2. use SQL Server 2005 Management Studio and estable Linked Server
   connection to Server B (on same AD)
3. I am able to successfully test the Linked Server connection to
   Server B from Server A

**Scenario #2**

1. Connect to Server A's SQL Server using SQL Server 2005
2. Try to establish linked server connection from Server A to Server B
   inside SSMS
3. The connection fails and throws the following error message:

> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]. 
>   OLE DB provider
>
> "SQLNCLI" for linked server "" returned message "Login
>   timeout expired".
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "" returned
>   message "An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the
>   server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused
>   by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow
>   remote connections.". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5)

**Questions**
Any ideas why? Is there something on my laptop that is blocking the linked server connection?
The reason why I need a linked server connection is so that I can run internal desktop applications; my workaround is to RDP into another server so that I can establish linked server connection

Answer (score 0):

How have you defined the linked server? Have a look at the below question on SO to see if it helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841339/having-trouble-adding-a-linked-sql-server

Comment: I used SQL Authenticaton to establish linked connection from Server A to Server B. When I RDP into Server A the connection works, but when I try to establish link by connecting to Server A via SSMS, the link fails. It's weird because I can establish link from localhost to Server B as well.

Comment: I am also referencing the server by name and not IP address

Comment: Try using the IP address instead.